# Blow-up, strict transform and gysin map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a non-singular, projective variety and $Y \subset X$ non-singular, projective subvariety. Denote by $\pi:W \to X$ the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$. Let $Y_1 \subset W$ be a non-singular subvariety of codimension $1$ such that the restriction $\pi:Y_1 \to \pi(Y_1)$ is an isomorphism. We assume that $Y_1$ intersects properly the exceptional divisor of $W$. Denote by $j_1:Y_1 \hookrightarrow W$ and $j_2:\pi(Y_1) \hookrightarrow X$. Is it then true that, $j_{1_*}:H^2(Y_1) \to H^4(W)$ is the same as $$H^2(Y_1) \cong H^2(\pi(Y_1)) \xrightarrow{j_{2_*}} H^4(X) \xrightarrow{\pi^*} H^4(W)?$$

Comment: No, that is not true.  Let $X$ be $\mathbb{P}^3$, let $Y$ be a line, let $\pi(Y_1)$ be a hyperplane that contains this line, let $Y_1$ be the strict transform of this hyperplane in the blowing up $W$, and consider the pushforward of the (cohomology class) of the divisor class in $Y_1$ of a line.  Thus pushforward to $H^4(X)$ is the class of a line, this is rationally equivalent to a line that is disjoint from $Y$, and hence the pullback class has zero intersection number with the exceptional divisor.  Yet the class of a line in $Y_1$ has intersection number $1$ with the exceptional divisor.

Comment: The correct formula that compares intersection numbers in $X$ and in the blowing up is sometimes called the "key formula" or "formule clef" for blowing up.